# Returning list from method - shorthand?

Tags: c#, list, return

Rather than declaring a list at the start of the method, adding to it and then returning it - I'm sure there's some shorthand return statement that can be written in a loop, for example, to save the extra code (declaring etc.) but I've forgot it. Anybody know what I mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[`yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)**:

```
public IEnumerable<int> BuildList()
{
    yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
}
```

Comment: Note that this returns an enumerable, not a list.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [`yield return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)

you can just use it like so to return elements in a loop:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetElements()
{      
   foreach(T t in listOfT)
   {
       // do some work
       yield return t;
       //code will continue here on next iteration       
   }
}
```

be aware that often you can use linq or the extension methods to so some work on all the elements of a list without having to write a function with a loop.  Like filtering the list for elements that [satisfy to some condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) or to [perform an operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) on all elements of a list.

Comment: You should omit the `(VS.80)` parts of MSDN URLs to get the latest version.

Comment: Thanks mate, that's what I'm after.

Comment: Also you want to use \`expression\` rather than \`expression' for keywords.